# Inserting Row at Index path issues

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am creating an iOS app that is set up as a hierarchy of data. I have no issues on the first page adding and deleting objects or even transitioning to the next page. The problem occurs on the second page which is set up exactly like the first. When I press the add button to add an object the program crashes and sends back the error SIGABRT.

```
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:YES]; << crashes on this line
```

here is the function add tapped:

```
- (void)addTapped:(id)sender {
    StudentDoc *newDoc = [[[StudentDoc alloc] initWithTitle:@"New Student" rating:0 thumbImage:nil fullImage:nil] autorelease];
    [_students addObject:newDoc];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_students.count-1 inSection:0];
    NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];    
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:YES];

    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
    [self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
 }
```

number of rows in section:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _students.count;
}
```

I have been under the impression that the count is what is causing the problem, but I have monitored the count and it stays consistent.

Overall I have no idea why it is crashing at this point because the page before it uses the exact same function to add objects on that page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Normally if you'd messed up your array or row indexes you'd expect an exception to be logged in the console, not a SIGABRT. Have you enabled NSZombies and break-on-exceptions in Xcode? That may help to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should put insert row at index path between begin updates and end updates block.

```
- (void)addTapped:(id)sender {

    StudentDoc *newDoc = [[[StudentDoc alloc] initWithTitle:@"New Student" rating:0 thumbImage:nil fullImage:nil] autorelease];
    [_students addObject:newDoc];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_students.count-1 inSection:0];
    NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];    

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:YES];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
    [self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done almost the same, tho I split it into 2 lines:

```
NSInteger idx = [_students count] - 1;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:idx inSection:0];
```

I wonder if that would make a difference.

Comment: That Still gives me the same error at insert row at index path

Comment: Can you put the whole method content into `@try { ... } @catch (NSException *e) { NSLog (@"exception %@", [e description]); }`?

Answer (score 0):

You're adding an object to the data source, but replacing an *existing* row in the table, not adding one, resulting in one row in the indexPath but 2 items in the data source array.

For instance, if you have one item in _students, you'll have one index path, {0,0}. When you add a row, you're adding it at indexPath {_students.count - 1, 0}, which would be {1 - 1, 0} or {0, 0}. Your data source should match any indexPaths you insert or remove, and in your case you're always ending up with one more item in your data source than you add/remove.

If you always want to add an item, instead of:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_students.count-1 inSection:0];
```

You want:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_students.count inSection:0];
```