# Tableview crashes on next reload index change

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

My tableview adds/delete cell into tableview on didselect of row and during this if table reload happens which sets new data set inside numberofrows in section to array causes to change all cell indexes and application crashes at cellForFow:atIndexPath: causing index of selected row in didselect has gets changed.

How can I delay new table reload event until following cell insertion completes:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:ipsArray 
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: I think we need more code to be able to help.

Comment: I think we couldn't track table reload event complete. As per answer here https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2598339 I am will be delaying next table reload call to make sure all previous indexes are set properly in first reload.

Comment: when you insert new row, did you insert new object to array?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26106561/4311935

Comment: Please show us more code for context. What method contains the lines you pasted here?

Comment: I update array first then update the table. During insert, if observer calls event to update table array then it was crashing due to index not found. Now I am delaying event table refresh to give the opportunity to previous table update to get complete.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue as follows: 
Reload table in following UIView Block and use a boolean isTableReloading variable to track table reload.

```Objective-c
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            weakSelf.isTableReloading = true;
            [weakSelf.tableView reloadData];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            weakSelf.isTableReloading = false;
        }];
```

In between above reload if a user taps a table cell and isTableReloading==true then delay didSelect method or ignore that call if your app permits.